# smarty3 display not working

Tags: templates, assign, smarty3

I post my code here first

index.php:

```
<?php
require('class/smarty/Smarty.class.php'); 
$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->setTemplateDir('./templates/');
$smarty->setCompileDir('./template_c/');
$smarty->setCacheDir('./cache/');
$smarty->setConfigDir('./configs/');

$smarty->assign('name','Dan Brown');  
$smarty->display('tpl_1.tpl');  
?>
```

template file, tpl_1.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>demo/title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
hello,{$name}
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

everything looks well, but the result is output blank page, smarty can't display or call the templates file, where is wrong in my code.
I really confuse this problem and waste too much times

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
require('class/smarty/Smarty.class.php'); 
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->setTemplateDir('./templates/');
$smarty->setCompileDir('./template_c/');
$smarty->setCacheDir('./cache/');
$smarty->setConfigDir('./configs/');

$smarty->assign('name','Dan Brown');  
$smarty->display('tpl_1.tpl');  
?>
```